# Gostaria de uma dica sobre checked, select option como eu faço para limpar os campos se uma pessoa seleciona uma opção

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Bom dia gostaria de uma dica sobre checked, select option como eu faço para limpar os campos se uma pessoa seleciona uma opção

```
<form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<!--# Valor=Cliente.Id #-->" />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            <label class="required">Tipo de cliente</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="rjuridica" class="switchVal" data-show="juridica" data-hide="fisica" name="atipo" value="juridica" <!--# Fazer=Cliente.ChecarTipo.Juridica #-->> 
                            <label for="rjuridica">Pessoa jurídica</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="rfisica" class="switchVal" data-show="fisica" data-hide="juridica" name="atipo" value="fisica" <!--# Fazer=Cliente.ChecarTipo.Fisica #-->>
                            <label for="rfisica">Pessoa física</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

gostaria que quando pessoa clicasse em pessoa jurídica limpasse o campo do imput cpf com informação antigas como pessoa fisica limpa-se o cnpj do campo

```
                                <div class="small-3 columns">
                                <label class="required">CPF</label>
                                <input class="cpf" type="text" name="acpf" value="<!--# Valor=Cliente.Cpf #-->"/>
                            </div>



                            <div class="small-3 columns">
                            <label class="required">CNPJ</label>
                            <input class="cnpj" type="text" name="acnpj" value="<!--# Valor=Cliente.CNPJ #-->"/>
                        </div>
```

por jquerry ou php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize `onclick`, assim quando clickar, irá apagar o conteudo do input.

https://jsfiddle.net/a0g21L1c/

```
$("#rjuridica").click(function(){
    $(".cpf").val(" ");
});
```

Com esta função, quando carregar no radio, ele irá limpar o input.

Comment: Funcionou obrigado XD

Comment: Um prazer ajudar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que essa limpeza envolve validação, e somente limpar o campo não irá impedir a submissão do mesmo, o ideal seria algo desse tipo...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                        var cpf = '';
                        var cnpj = '';
                        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
                          if($(this).val() == 'juridica'){
                     if($('.cpf').val() != cpf){cpf = $('.cpf').val();}
                           $('.cpf').val('');
                           $('.cpf').attr('disabled', 'true');
                            $('.cnpj').removeAttr('disabled');
                            $('.cnpj').val(cnpj);
                          }else{
                          if($('.cnpj').val() != cnpj){cnpj = $('.cnpj').val();}
                           $('.cnpj').val('');
                            $('.cnpj').attr('disabled', 'true');
                            $('.cpf').removeAttr('disabled');
                            $('.cpf').val(cpf);
                          }
                        })
                        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<!--# Valor=Cliente.Id #-->" />

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 columns">
                            <label class="required">Tipo de cliente</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="rjuridica" class="switchVal" data-show="juridica" data-hide="fisica" name="atipo" value="juridica">
                            <label for="rjuridica">Pessoa jurídica</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="rfisica" class="switchVal" data-show="fisica" data-hide="juridica" name="atipo" value="fisica">
                            <label for="rfisica">Pessoa física</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="small-3 columns">
                                <label class="required">CPF</label>
                                <input class="cpf" type="text" name="acpf" value=""/>
                            </div>



                            <div class="small-3 columns">
                            <label class="required">CNPJ</label>
                            <input class="cnpj" type="text" name="acnpj" value=""/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica mas eu quero que mandei em branco mesmo para banco por causa que esse seleção é para altera tipo do cliente e apagar o antigo mas mesmo assim obrigado XD